# How would someone use the Iridium Browser with Tor?

Tags: configuration

The [Iridium Browser](https://iridiumbrowser.de) looks like a viable competitor to the Firefox-based component in TorBrowser. How would someone use Iridium with the Tor network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Iridum is based on Chromium, [instructions for using Chrome w/ Tor should work](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/how-do-i-configure-chrome-to-use-tor).  Of course - just like using Chrome/Chromium with Tor is not recommended, I wouldn't recommend using Iridium with Tor either.

For one matter: you'll stand out as one of the very few people (only?) using Iridium over Tor.  Your cross-domain and session unlinkability is gone.

Secondly, Maintaining Chromium forks is *hard*. Chromium has no Extended Support Release cycle. This introduces a difficult dependency cycle of [BugFix 1] -> [Major Release] -> [BugFix 2].  To get the second fix, you have to either accept the Major Release (including auditing the entire thing for proxy issues, fingerprinting, or cross-domain leakage) or backporting the BugFix.  Other attempts at maintaining a secure fork of Chromium (Aviator) did not go well.