# "This is a SOCKS Proxy, Not An HTTP Proxy"

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, proxy, socks, https

As the title says, I've been trying to use Tor as a proxy for Postman and I'm getting the following response when I try to make a request to a specific endpoint that **does not support HTTPS**

> This is a SOCKS Proxy, Not An HTTP Proxy
>
> ## This is a SOCKs proxy, not an HTTP proxy.
>
> It appears you have configured your web browser to use this Tor port as
>   an HTTP proxy.
>
> This is not correct: This port is configured as a SOCKS proxy, not
>   an HTTP proxy. If you need an HTTP proxy tunnel, use the HTTPTunnelPort
>   configuration option in place of, or in addition to, SOCKSPort.
>   Please configure your client accordingly.
>
> See 
>               https://www.torproject.org/documentation.html for more information.

But the thing is, when I use the Tor **browser**, I can visit the same site just fine.

So what is the browser doing different than my "tor.exe" proxy? Are there any ways around this?

Comment: The question was about how to run tor.exe from Windows, I have to laugh at looking at the responses from the Linux console. If the author of the answer is no longer what is Windows and what is Linux is useless. Run the polipo or old privoxy on the Windows port configuration.

Answer (score 17):

Tor provides a SOCKS proxy by default.

Whatever you've configured to use Tor is trying to use it as an HTTP proxy which is a different kind of proxy protocol.

Tor (at least as of 0.3.2.x) can provide an `HTTPTunnelPort` which provides an HTTP CONNECT proxy interface. If the application is capable of using an HTTP connect proxy (instead of a transparent HTTP proxy) then you should be able to configure Tor by running, for example, `tor.exe --HTTPTunnelPort 8118` from the command line, which would give you an HTTP CONNECT proxy on port 8118.

If applications cannot support HTTP CONNECT or SOCKS then they will not be able to use Tor without using Transparent Proxying to force internet connections to use Tor.

Comment: i was having this problem with gradle in android studio. this solution worked for me

Comment: I was able to config and use tor using `HTTPTunnelPort` option, but now I can only open `https` sites, is there any flag/config resolve this problem?

Answer (score 9):

As @cacahuatl said you can use that switch, if you want it to be permanent go to `/etc/tor/torrc` (This is the path for tor config file in Ubuntu and Debian), open it with your favorite text editor and add `HTTPTunnelPort 9080` at the end of the file, reset tor service with this command:

`sudo service tor restart`

and you're done.

Comment: Thanks so much, How can i use this proxy in my bash shell?

Comment: Before anything run the below command to see which port being used by tor. `sudo netstat -tpln | grep tor` , forth column is address and port which tor listening to, mine is `127.0.0.1:9050` . then whenever you want to use it in your script address it like this `socks5://127.0.0.1:9050`.