# OpenVPN Client over Tor as proxy

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, proxy, openvpn

I'm trying to connect to a remote OpenVPN server using OpenVPN Connect Client on a Windows PC.
The Open Connect Client has a proxy option in the GUI, for this I configured to use TOR as a proxy.
IP `127.0.0.1`
port `9051`
I have kept the `Tor browser` open so that the port is available. No changes have been made to the `torrc` file.

Without the proxy the connection works fine.

However when I try to connect with the proxy.
I get the following error.

[image]

Any clues as to what is going wrong here would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tor Browser runs a SOCKS proxy on port 9150, but OpenVPN Connect expects an HTTP proxy.

There are two types of HTTP proxies, GET proxies and CONNECT proxies. Tor only supports HTTP CONNECT proxies if you enable the [`HTTPTunnelPort`](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#HTTPTunnelPort) option in your tor configuration file (the `torrc` file). I would think that OpenVPN expects an HTTP CONNECT proxy so I think this will work, but I can't find any actual documentation about what type it expects.

Comment: Amazing answer!! Genius! running tor with that option worked. and then OpenVPN client connected via TOR! Not sure what pro / con this method has over Socks5 though? Also see https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/16554/this-is-a-socks-proxy-not-an-http-proxy

Comment: BTW, OpenVPN Connect Client, also supports, parameters like `socks-proxy` however when I use them to use tor (127.0.0.1:9051) in the openvpn client `.conf` file they don't take effect. Any ideas why?

Comment: @ChrisBean I'm not sure, but [this article](https://kiljan.org/2017/11/15/routing-traffic-through-openvpn-using-a-local-socks-proxy/) says that OpenVPN has a routing issue when the SOCKS proxy is running on localhost, so you might be running into the same problem.